# How to change the contents of dynamically created div tags?

Tags: php, javascript

My javascript function is as below. It gets all the parameter values. But the function is not working. Please any suggestions?

```
function getProductData(dealNo,title,url)
{
    // following line is not working
    document.getElementById(dealNo).innerHTML = "whatever";

}
```

edit: dealNo is the id of the dynamically created div tag

Comment: what is the value of `dealNo`

Comment: Is the element an `<input>`?

Comment: is `dealNo` the actual id or a placehoder variable which holds the id

Comment: Works here http://fiddle.jshell.net/AVcwP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be OK. This is example from your code http://jsfiddle.net/4VNL7/. Check is `dealNo` getting correct id and that id is already in HTML. Maybe you are trying to modify `div` that is not in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById('dealNo').innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add text to an existing div, try this 
     document.getElementById('dealNo').innerText = "Hello"

of if you want to place an html to the existing div, try this
     document.getElementById('dealNo').innerHTML = "Hello"

if they are not working, see whether your div Id is indeed 'dealNo'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery to add to text div which are dynamically added.

HTML

```
<div id="containerDiv"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var divVariable = $('div');
$(divVariable).html('This is text in div');
$('#containerDiv').append(divVariable);
```

In above code I have created divVariable with div HTML instance, also appended text to that new created div in memory. Finally that div is appended to containerDiv (i.e. parent div).

Dynamically div is child div.

Check this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/87a6e/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,It was my fault. I haven't cleared the magento cache. That was the issue. Thank you all